# Why does this React's useEffect() fires twice after loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this very simple component called `Editor`:

```
export default function Editor() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/pages")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setCurrentData(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return (
      <LoadingError value={error.message} />
    );
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return (
      <Loading />
    )
  } else {
    console.log(currentData);
  }

  return ( <div></div> );
}
```

Notice the last `else` condition,  where my `currentData` is logged into the console.

What happens when this component is rendered is that my `console.log()` fires twice! The first time my `currentData` object is empty. The second time, the object properly contains all the data from my API.

However, as my `console.log()` should fire only when there is no error (the first `if` condition), and only when the data is loaded (the second `else if` condition),  how is it possible that I end up with empty object in the console the first time? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your useEffect execute 1 time but because you change usetate duration excaute useEffect your component render twice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `useEffect` only fires once. You're seeing the `console.log` output twice because you're doing `updateState` twice. Change the order to see the expected behaviour you're looking for

This is what's happening right now:

```
setIsLoaded(true); // Causes 1st rerender and so console.log executes with []
setCurrentData(result); // Causes second rerender and console.log has data.
```

What you want:

```
setCurrentData(result); // Causes 1st rerender but does not reach the else statement
setIsLoaded(true); // Reaches the else statement and currentData is already set
```

This will make sure your currentData is set before `isLoaded` is set to `true`

As of now, React does not batch update state calls in the above scenario, but this will change once React v18 is released.

Comment: Feel free to accept this one, it's obviously better and goes into more detail and is more useful. Four minutes will hardly matter for future visitors :)

Comment: Excellent! Is this mean that in the first render, data is set, but because 'isLoaded' is false, it does not log,  and in the next render, because 'isLoaded' is true, it does log? ok, but Aren't these two (setIsLoaded & setCurrentData) done in a fraction of a second? That means the question code must work!!

Comment: done in a fraction of a second - thats the problem though, there is still a _difference_ of when it happens, which can be noticed on the scree between paints

Comment: @andymccullough. I'm not understanding! I mean, we should not feel the difference between the two and feel both did in the first render. Is possible to more explain?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Try looking at this repl I made: https://replit.com/@Harkunwar/HighlevelUntidyEllipse#src/App.jsx

I reproduced the same thing happening above but with a simpler example.

Comment: Thanks for this practical example:) Another question! In your answer, when 'setCurrentData(result);', will be closed 'useEffect', and in the next render, again will be opened? (because runs 'useEffect' after any render) Or will be staying in the react's mind that must run the continue 'useEffect'? @Harkunwar

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi `useEffect` will evaluate immediately both set calls and put them in a render queue. Then it will run the render with the first set call, then it will run the render with the second set call. Let's say you put a `console.log` after calls to `setIsLoaded` and `setCurrentData`, that `console.log` will execute before the `console.log` executed due to both rerenders.

Comment: pretty good! Do you mean that React first sees both 'setState', so first will execute 'console.log' that placed after of these?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this React's useEffect() fires twice after loaded?

It doesn't.

The function `Editor` runs again because you call `setIsLoaded` and `setCurrentData` once the promise in the effect (which runs only once) resolves.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that React only batches state updates for certain handlers, like `onClick` and others, but I have feeling that when state updates occur in the callback of a promise, they dont get batched, so you will have two renders happening in your case.

edit - which is probably what @Harkunwar's answer is alluding to, in that the order in which you update your state matters

Comment: This is correct, but will change in React 18: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21